# In what circumstances does Python3 Numpy hand me a reference, rather than a copy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was working with numpy matrices yesterday, and I encountered a behavior which made me double take, specifically:

```
>>> X=np.array([[1,5],[2,4],[3,6]])
>>> X
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]]) # Perfecto
>>> a=X[:,0]
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])  # Exactly
>>> X
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]]) #Yup
>>> a[0]=999
>>> a
array([999,   2,   3]) # :)  
>>> X
array([[999,   5],
       [  2,   4],
       [  3,   6]]) # Errrrr, Huh?  
#OK, Fine.
>>> b=np.matrix(X[:,1])
>>> b
matrix([[5, 4, 6]])
>>> b[0]=666
>>> X
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]]) # That's what I wanted
```

I originally expected that the Python would implicitly assume my data type was np.matrix, and call a copy constructor.  Instead?  I got a reference to the existing Matrix.  Being a C programmer in my heart....I HATE reference variables.  I'd rather get back a memory location and explicitly in the code DE-REFERENCE the memory location and cast the assignment.
But...Brave New Worlds require open mindedness.  I assume this is a nuance of Numpy.  So I ask, is there a rule of thumb in Python libraries when I should expect to get a reference back on assignment?  That unexpected result was uglier than a monkey's armpit

Comment: In none of these cases were you handed a "reference", or rather, in all cases you were, but in each case, it was a reference to a *new object*. But that new object may just be a *view* over a buffer shared with the original numpy array object. This is a *feature* of numpy, which is pretty clearly documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the part about "C" vs references. This is no more references than what you are used to in C (besides, it happens to be C, since this is numpy). I am C programmer my self. And hate references myself (I mean, the ones of C++). I want to pass pointer to variable that can be modified, indeed. But this is not one.

In C

```c
int arr[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
int *subarr=arr+3; 
subarr[0]=99; 
printf("%d\n", arr[3]);
```

also prints 99. That is what you are doing here with your example. You extract a subarray.

That array contains a pointer to data that are the same

As I said, no only you could code that exact behavior in C. But in fact it IS coded in C. In C, arrays are pointers too. When you pass an array arr to a function, even if arr itself is passed by value, that is that function cannot modify arr itself (no more than you are modifying `X` in your example), that function can still change the content of `arr`. Exactly as you changed the content of `X` here. Really, there is no difference. You don't have a reference to `X`. But still, the subarray share the data pointed inside `X` structure.

As for your exact question, strict answer is "it depends, but it is said in the documentation". But rule of thumb is "when it can, it usually shares the data" (what you call "hand a reference"). To guess when it can, you have to understand what is a numpy array: it is a bunch of contiguous data, a shape, a initial pointer, a dtype and strides. So that element at index `[i1,i2,...,in]` exists iff `ik<shapeₖ` for all k, and that element is at address `data+stride₁×i₁+stride₂×i₂+…+stridesₖ×iₖ`

Usually (rule of thumb), if an operation can be done by building a new set of strides/shape, but with the same data, then it is done that way, without copying data.

So, your example `X[:,1]`: assuming that data is at address `Xaddr`, shape is `(shapeX1, shapeX2)` and strides is `(strideX1, strideX2)`, then an array `Y` whose address is `Yaddr=Xaddr+1×strideX2`, whose shape is `(shapeX1,)`, and stride is `(strideX1,)`, is that second column of `X`. So, since it is possible to just do that to compute `X[:,1]`, then the copy is avoided (again, not a strict rule just one of thumb).

Likewise `X.T` (transpose) is the array whose address is `Xaddr`, whose shape is `(shapeX2,shapeX1)` and strides `(strideX2,strideX1)`. So, no need to copy, so it is not.
So

```py
X=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
X.T[0,0]=99
X
```

shows

```
array([[99,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

On the other hand, complex indexing generates a copy.

```py
X=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
X[[0,2,3], :][0,0]=99
X
```

shows

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Because you can't do that advanced indexing by just tweaking strides and shapes.

Note that, `X[::2,:][0,0]=99` does change X. When `X[[0,2],:][0,0]` doesn't. Yet `X[::2,:]` and `X[[0,2],:]` mean the same thing (keeping only even lines). But the first one is always feasible with just strides tweaking, when the second happens only to be with this numbers, but wouldn't if the line selection weren't evenly chosen (as in my previous `[0,2,3]` example).

That rule of thumb works even for quite complex cases.

For example

```py
X=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
Y=X.reshape(6,2)
Y[0,0]=111
print(X[0,0]) # 111
Z=X[:2,:2]
Z[0,0]=222
print(X[0,0]) # 222
T=Z.reshape(1,4)
T[0,0]=333
print(X[0,0], Y[0,0], Z[0,0]) # 222 222 222, not 333
```

So, the first reshape (Y) is a "view", when the second (T) is a copy.

Why, because X data are contiguous. A bit like if in C you had implemented it like this

```c
int *x=malloc(12);
for(int i=0;i<12;i++) x[i]=i;
int xstride1=sizeof(int)*3, xstride2=sizeof(int);
// x[i,j] is *(int *)((char *)x+xstride1*i+xstride2*j)

int *y=x; // same 12 consecutive numbers
int ystride1=sizeof(int)*2, ystride2=sizeof(int);
// y[i,j] is *(int *)((char *)y+ystride1*i+ystride2*j)

int *z=x;
int zstride1=sizeof(int)*3, zstride2=sizeof(int);
// z[i,j] is *(int *)((char *)z+zstride1*i+zstride2*j)
// Some exactly same as x. Normal: we only changed shape.

// But you can't do anything like
int *t=x;
int tstride1=???, int stride2=???;
// t[i,j] is *(int *)((char *)t+i*tstride1+j*tstride2)()
```

There aren't any `tstride1`, `tstride2` for which this is true. Just observe `t` values: they are values 0,1,3,4, extracted from `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11`. They are not evenly distributed in the initial array of data. So, there isn't a unique `tstrid2` telling how many bytes separates both 0 for 1, and 1 from 3, and 3 from 4.
So, impossible to build `T` without building a new set of data.

Reason why the, apparently same, operation, `.reshape(...)` sometimes returns a view, sometimes returns a copy.

But all that is stated in the documentation. Some operation clearly return a copy. Some clearly return a view. And for some documentation says "you can't make any assumption whether it is a view or a copy".
Because it depends on how smart the implementation is to detect whether it can reuse the initial data or not.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I scoped the doc after you pointed me to the term "view"   "When you assign an array or its elements to a new variable, you have to explicitly numpy.copy the array, otherwise the variable is a view into the original array."

Comment: My point about "References."  The documentation even says "if you delete an array, but you fail to delete a view of that array, the memory hangs around." IE. the reference count went up.  In my opinion, copy construction should be the default behavior, I shouldn't have to add "copy" to it.  But that's ok, I'm RTFMing.

Comment: That is another meaning of the word "reference". In python, there isn't any `malloc` nor `free` as, you are certainly aware (well, with numpy, there is some sort of `malloc`, since we do create arrays, with `np.zeros` or `np.empty`. And there is a `del` operator in python. But most of the time, we don't need it). How its work, is using reference count. Each times you create a reference to an object, a reference count is incremented. Each time that reference count reach 0, the object is destroyed (that's basically what a garbage collector does)

Comment: So, this is not just for numpy. `s="hello"; t=s` does the same. This is python's model. Even `x=1` means that x is a reference to the object `1`. Nothing to do with numpy. But, well, in `C` if you define `typedef float **Matrix`, with the allocation, setter, getters, etc, you wouldn't expect `Matrix a=b` to be a copy of `b`. So think of numpy arrays as arrays, ie pointers to a bunch of data. With a set of operations defined on them. Some creating a new array (with a malloc) and returning it to you, some other, just returning the same pointer.

Comment: Anyway, numpy or not, C or not, that would be really inefficient if everything was always a copy. But, well, I feel I am just obfuscating things. The best indeed is you continue to rftm. But I also feel that part is the problem is not really about numpy, but about python's data model (how in python everything is a reference). Since you are in a reading mood, you may want to read about that too :D

Answer (score 1):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html

Your arrays:

```
In [116]: X=np.array([[1,5],[2,4],[3,6]])
In [117]: X
Out[117]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]])
In [118]: a=X[:,0]
In [119]: a
Out[119]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

This is `basic indexing`, so `a` is a `view`.  Check its `base`:

```
In [120]: a.base
Out[120]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

More information on the arrays:

```
In [123]: X.__array_interface__
Out[123]: 
{'data': (94507967116736, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
In [124]: a.__array_interface__
Out[124]: 
{'data': (94507967116736, False),
 'strides': (16,),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
```

Note the same `data` number.  This is, sort of, the pointer to the data buffer of the array (a c array).  Read  more numpy basics to learn how arrays are stored.

Your matrix is a copy, with its own base:

```
In [125]: m=np.matrix(X)
In [126]: m.base
```

A view version of the matrix:

```
In [127]: m=np.asmatrix(X)
In [128]: m.base
Out[128]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

You can also specify `copy` to be sure the new array is its own base:

```
In [129]: a.copy().base
```

`advanced indexing` produces a copy:

```
In [130]: b = X[:,[0]]
In [131]: b
Out[131]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Note the different shape, (3,1), instead of (3,) for `a`.

```
In [132]: b.base
Out[132]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Checking the base reveals a nuance to the indexing. This base is a (1,3) array, not `X` or `a`.  The indexing step actually made this (1,3) array, and finished it off by returning  its transpose (a view making step).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use 'copy' to obtain a new independent object. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
b = np.matrix(X[:,1]).copy()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).